# Elasticsearch - aggregation and sort

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have a .json file with a few records of the following format:

```
{
        "first_name": "Kurt",
        "last_name": "Cobain",
        "num": "998-555-7385",
        "email": "kurt_cobain@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "street_address": "607 Washington St.",
            "city": "Blackwater",
            "state": "NH",
            "postal_code": "97183"
        },
        "unique_id": "5998dd23fc13ae04d9000001",
        "job_profile": "intern",
        "company": "netflix",
        "creation_date": "2021-08-01 16:30:05",
        "countries_visited": [
                                {
                                    "country_name": "India",
                                    "country_code": "IND",
                                    "date_of_visiting": "2021-07-27"

                                },
                                {
                                        "country_name": "Germany",
                                        "country_code": "GER",
                                        "date_of_visiting": "2021-07-29"

                                },{
                                        "country_name" :"USA",
                                        "country_code": "USA",
                                        "date_of_visiting": "2021-07-31"

                              },
                              {
                                        "country_name": "France",
                                        "country_code": "FRA",
                                        "date_of_visiting": "2021-07-31"

                              },
                              {
                                        "country_name": "India",
                                        "country_code": "IND",
                                        "date_of_visiting": "2021-07-31"

                              }
                            ]

    }
```

I need to write a query to see how many people visited India (or any particular country), and the count of people must be ordered according to the date_of_visiting (ASCENDING ORDER).
Result should look something like:

2021-07-25 : 10

2021-07-26 : 8

2021-07-27 : 13

2021-07-28 : 4

and so on

I tried using aggs and post_filter. I am getting a 400 status code. Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Could you please share the query you have tried and some sample data with expected result for the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query would be something like below:

```
{ 
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "countries_visited",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "countries_visited.country_name": {
            "value": "India"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "countries_visited"
      },"aggs": {
        "histogram": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "countries_visited.date_of_visiting",
            "interval": "day"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the query part your select the country name. the second part provide you a `date_histogram` function. If you also want to find countries and number of travelers to these country by one query you can add a `term` aggs before `date_histogram` aggs. Please let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Postman for ES querying, not ELK. So I had to delete the index, set the mapping of countries_visited to nested, and then insert the records. Thanks a lot!